# Substituting an indexed variable with an expression

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sum over `A[i]` and want to change it into a sum over `B[i] / 2`.

I can change it into a sum over `B[i]` like this:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import *
A = IndexedBase('A')
B = IndexedBase('B')
SA = Sum(A[i], (i, a, b))
SB = SA.subs(A, B)
```

But I want to do something to the effect of

```
SB2 = SA.subs(A,B/2)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks a bit like a bug in SymPy.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use `replace` instead of `subs`. I haven't completely grok'ed the difference, but some more info can be found in [Difference between replace and subs?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sympy/b_Yv6s15Y0Q)

```
SB.replace(A[i], B[i]/2)
```

which returns

```
Sum(B[i]/2, (i, a, b))
```